# How do you extract the undersampled data from caret in R?

Tags: r, r-caret

I created a random forest model using the `train` function from caret with the following train control parameters:

```
    ctrl <- trainControl(sampling = "down")
    
    set.seed(123)
    rf_fit <- train(Dep ~., 
                    data = dt_train, 
                    method = "rf",
                    metric = "Kappa",
                    trControl = ctrl,
                    importance = TRUE)
```

My forest is performing well and now I need to sort of explain it in simpler terms. I am using `inTrees` package to do that but to proceed, I need the undersampled data first that was generated from `train`.

Is there any way that I can get the undersampled data from `train` function?

Comment: I do not think this is possible. The only logical argument for this would be `returnData = TRUE` in `trainControl` however this always returns the data set supplied as `data` argument to `train`.

Comment: oh okay. that's a bummer. I guess I really need to recreate my model using `ROSE` and `randomforest` instead. thanks!